# Updating a dll in a winforms app from a separate project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms app with some code in a class library. The winforms app references the class library and its dll. If I make a change to the class library, what is the most efficient way to update the dll in the winforms app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the answer simple: use a post-build events to copy the new DLL to the windows executable folder.

Another option: use project references instead of file references and you will get all this handled automatically by Visual Studio.